# check if passed context is Empty in Template

Tags: python, django

what I'm trying to achieve here is if context is empty or if **STUDENT** variable is empty, instead of returning all students. it should return none and in template it shows No results found.
currently when nothing is stored in **q** my template render all the students.

**in views.**

```
def student_home(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ""
    
    students = Student.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=q) | Q(last_name__icontains = q) | Q(grade__icontains=q))
    context = {'students': students}
    return render(request, 'StudentManager/home.html', context)
```

**search-bar in NAVBAR.**

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search" action='{% url 'student_home' %}'>
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" name='q' placeholder="Search Student" aria-label="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background: #fff2df;">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all students with `q = ""` because `Student.objects.filter(first_name__icontains="")` means for django return all `Student` where `first_name` is not `None`.

Try this

```
def student_home(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if q:
        students = Student.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=q) | Q(last_name__icontains = q) | Q(grade__icontains=q))
    else:
        students = []
    context = {'students': students}
    return render(request, 'StudentManager/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is confused: in your code, it does not exist a **STUDENT** variable.

you can just check students variable in your template:

```
{% if not students %}
No results found
{% endif %}
```